# Standalone Java application in Google Cloud App Engine connecting to Google Cloud SQL database

Tags: java, spring, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**Goal:** Run a standalone Java & Database application in the cloud for performance, scalability and high availability

**Application Details**

- Spring Boot based Java application is git cloned in to a folder on
  the Google App Engine Standard Environment.
- Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation instance created

***Note:*** The Cloud Shell is in the same Google Cloud project as the Cloud SQL

**Google Cloud Shell**

```
user@${PROJECT_ID}:~$ cd git

user@${PROJECT_ID}:~$ cd myapplication
```

Running application using Maven throws exception not being able to connect to the Cloud SQL database

```
user@${PROJECT_ID}:~$ mvn exec:java
```

Using different JDBC connection strings and JDBC drivers did not help.

**application.properties**

```
# Use MySQL database
#etl.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${IP:Instance_name}/${database}?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
#etl.datasource.url=jdbc:google:mysql://${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}/${database}
etl.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/${database}?cloudSqlInstance=${INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME}&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false
#etl.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
etl.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver
etl.datasource.username=${user}
etl.datasource.password=${password}
```

> 2017-08-03 10:40:59.477 ERROR 381 --- [MyApplication.main()]
>   o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial
>   connections of pool.
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3
>   times. Giving up.
>
> 2017-08-03 12:16:23.525 ERROR 1048 --- [MyApplication.main()]
>   o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial
>   connections of pool. java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver from
>   ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@13b428de;ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@13b428de

Even adding a src/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml did not help.

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

**Questions**

1. Is Google App Engine only for Web based applications?
2. Is the Google App Engine Flexible environment suitable for non-web console based Java applications?
3. Or should I be using the Google Compute Engine VM platform to run such non-web console applications and similar to running on my local computer?
4. Is there a Maven dependency that can be added for com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver?

Comment: Are your CloudSQL instance and App in the same GCP project?

Comment: Is the application.properties file pasted above the one which is deployed? Or is it just a representative sample pasted as an examples?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do should be absolutely possible on App Engine.
There is indeed a Maven dependency you can pull for the Google Driver:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also, since you're using Spring Boot, I would suggest you give [Spring Cloud GCP](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp) a try. There is a simple [Cloud SQL sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-sql-sample) there that can get you started quickly.